# Unable to read json {object1}{object2}{object3}.....from Java language

Tags: java, json

I am working on getting hashtags list from tweets collection , I gathered tweets into file and then append to a string through bufferReader.

If I write **JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(String name)** ,then I am able to read only Object1 JSON data. After this point I got stuck and not sure how do I get second ,third and so on iteratively. Is there any programming way to find array of JSON objects from the string(which has JSON data) or any other way?

Comment: I can't understand anything about your question. Post your code, post example input. Tell precisely what you want the code to do with that input and what it does instead.

Comment: You have to do further work on `obj`. Use `getJSONArray()`, for example.

Comment: JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(String name) JSONObject Object2=obj.getJSONObject("String_name2");

Comment: I had file which has multiple JSON root elements of tweets.Each tweet is independent ,didn't have JSON array structre. 
For exanple { tweet1} {tweet2} {tweet3}......
As it is in file I am storing it in string ,from there I am reading JSONObject then I am able to get only tweet1 from that string, not able to get rest of the tweet2 ,tweet3 JSON root elements
I hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating the JSON Object Representations, would need to start with JSON Array representation and each of the JSON Object Representation should be separated by comma.

```
public class JSonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json1 = "{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"A green door\", \"price\": 12.50,  \"tags\": [\"home\", \"green\"]}";

        String json2 = "{ \"id\": 2, \"name\": \"A blue door\", \"price\": 1.50,  \"tags\": [\"home\", \"blue\"]}";

        // Printing concatenated JSON Representation
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json1 + json2); // Will see only
                                                                // first object
        System.out.println(jsonObject);

        // Printing Array representation
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray("[" + json1 + "," + json2 + "]");
        System.out.println(array);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"tags":["home","green"],"id":1,"price":12.5,"name":"A green door"}
[{"tags":["home","green"],"id":1,"price":12.5,"name":"A green door"},{"tags":["home","blue"],"id":2,"price":1.5,"name":"A blue door"}]
```